# Intent sharing with android studio only showing image not text

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I am trying to share an image url and a title for that image from my android studio app , however only the image is appearing when I apply the code without a text.

The image is being sent correctly but no text is accompanying it.

This is the code I am using :

```
 var  shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                shareIntent.setType("*/*")
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Look at this image")
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri)
                shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share with"))
```

"Look at this image" not appearing

Comment: `shareIntent.setType("image/*")`

Comment: Even when I added that type , it still only shows the image without a text

Comment: `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Look at this image"))` ?

Comment: @Darkman this is start a chooser to pick which app I'm gonna share the data to

Comment: Then ***"Look at this image" not appearing*** is not clear to me. Can you post an image?

Comment: @Darkman the image is appearing normally , but this is the part that is not appearing upon sharing shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Look at this image")

Comment: Try using `android.intent.extra.SUBJECT` or `android.intent.extra.TITLE`.